# WPF окна не обмениваются данными

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть два окна WPF, я пробую между ними делать обмен данными, например:

```
    public partial class Window2 : Window //класс второго окна, которое вызывается кнопокой из главного окна
    {
        public int numb_car;
        MainWindow main_wnd_sender = new MainWindow();//экземпляр главного окна
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    private void Button_save_car(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//событие нажатия кнопки
    {
        numb_car = list_car.SelectedIndex + 1; //list_car - ComboBox
        main_wnd_sender.car_prop.Text = list_car.SelectedItem.ToString();//car_prop - textbox на главном окне
    }
```

Тут я просто пытаюсь отобразить содержимое КомбоБокса с окна, которое вызываем главным окном, на ТекстБоксе на главном окне. Компилятор не ругается, всё запускается, но ничего не происходит. Пробовал вывести переменную `numb_car` в главном окне, но тоже ничего не происходи и в MessageBox выводится `0` а не то, что хранится в переменной во втором окне. Может я чего-то не дописал? Может просто не понимаю то, как должно это реализовываться?

Comment: Поймите основы основ WPF! WPF, это XAML разметка и привязки (binding), без них вы сами себе придумываете геморой. По поводу вашей проблемы - на SO была уйма подобных вопросов, можно ведь поискать, не? Ок, что по вашему `new MainWindow();//экземпляр главного окна` - экземпляр текущего или нового окна? Подсказка `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В WPF не хранят данные в окнах и вообще зачастую код в классе окна не пишут. В WPF используют шаблон проектирования **MVVM** и привязки данных `Binding` в XAML.*

Но ваша проблема возникла на уровне ООП, а не работы с данными. В ООП есть такое понятие "объект". И вы предположили, что `new` возвращает вам ссылку на объект того же типа, который вы запросили, если он ранее был создан. Но возвращает он вам на самом деле новый, только что созданный объект, не имеющий ничего общего с тем, что вам нужно.

```cs
MainWindow window1 = new MainWindow();
MainWindow window2 = new MainWindow();
window1.Show();
window2.Show();
```

Этот код создаст вам 2 совершенно одинаковых окна типа `MainWindow`, которые никак друг с другом не будут связаны.

Чтобы исправить ошибку методом "в лоб", не учитывая, что в WPF то что вы делаете, не делается в принципе, то можно пойти следующим путем:

```cs
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public int numb_car;
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public Window2(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
    
    private void Button_save_car(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numb_car = list_car.SelectedIndex + 1;
        _mainWindow.car_prop.Text = list_car.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

А в коде главного окна создать новое `Window2` вот так:

```cs
Window2 window2 = new Window2(this);
window2.Show();
```

Тогда ссылка на сущестующее главное окно действительно будет передана в дочернее окно, и к нему можно будет обращаться.

[Но лучше начните изучать, как работать с WPF правильно](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php), [вот ещё примерчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567).

Comment: Спасибище огромнейшее! Я обязательно ознакомлюсь с Биндами, но чутка позже.