# Как найти определенную «фигуру» в двумерном массиве С#?

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Есть вот такой массив, симулирует UV текстуру где 1 - черный, 0 - белый цвета. В текстуре есть пятна(зоны) как показано ниже это 4 квадрата.

```
var texture = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
          new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        };
```

Как построить новый массив и определить эти пятна номером? Первое пятно - 1, второе - 2 и т.д.
Примерно так:

```
[000000000000000]
[000111100222200]
[000111100222200]
[000111100222200]
[000000000000000]
```

Это требуется чтобы найти потом центры этих фигур.
То есть конечная задача поиск центров зон. Предполагал что выделение зон по типу 1 -2 -3 и потом прогон по ключам даст мне понимание о фигуре. Но вот сам алгоритм поиска фигуры(зоны) не могу придумать.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: Немного не то, там вычлинение фигуры из общей картины. И как итог отдельные битмапы каждой из фигур, в таком случае невозможно найти центр фигуры относительно ее стандартного расположения

Comment: Зачем все новички мучаются со списками, проще же `int[][]` использовать, да и работать быстрее будет.

Comment: Можно даже [как-то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322378/373567) поизвращаться.

Comment: `в таком случае невозможно найти центр фигуры` это почему? Никаких отдельных битмапов выделение компонентов не даёт.

Comment: @MBo Если меть массив с нумерованными фигурами то по ним можно найти минимальный и максимальный и минимальный элемент по индексу, разделив Y на 2 получим центр фигуры по Y, и это же будет являться индексом для X строки. Найдя в ней минимальный и максимальный элемент так же разделим на 2 и получим центр фигуры. Все просто. Проблема лишь определить эти фигуры(зоны). Я пока так и не смог.

Comment: Приведённый алгоритм решает задачу определения фигур. Если его трудно реализовать, то простым floodfill можно добиться аналогичного результата.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас предполагаются зоны одинакового размера, то достаточно найти их левые верхние углы простым перебором, а середину просто вычислить например [row+длина/2][col+высота/2], а если размеры пятен одинаковые и они квадратные, то середина не нужна вовсе для вычисления образуемой ими фигуры.

Comment: Нет, зоны(фигуры) имеют рандомные площади. В примере я использовал квадраты чтобы показать наглядность их смещения относительно друг друга.