# Реализация динамического приложения на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, dynamic

так как я только *начинаю* свой путь в WPF, то хотел бы уточнить несколько моментов у знающих людей:

- Есть ли возможность реализовать приложение без MVVM(чтобы при этом оно было "правильно" написано)?
- Как сделать приложение динамическим (например, чтобы менялась информация полученная извне?

Comment: 1) нет никакого «правильно». WPF был разработан с прицелом на MVVM. Вы можете конечно и не использовать MVVM, но тогда будете страдать. Это то же самое, что брать отвертку и гвозди ей забивать.

Comment: 2) брать и делать. Вы бы ещё спросили «как сделать хорошо». С такой вашей постановкой вопроса ответ как должен выглядеть? Я вот даже вопроса не понял.

Comment: Чем вас так пугает MVVM? Вас не будет пугать куча кода 3000 строк, наваленного в одном .cs файле? Как в этом разбираться потом. MVVM всего-лишь предлагает грубо говоря интерфейс писать в одном классе, логику приоложения в другом, а данные хранить в третьем и стараться связывать эти классы как можно слабее, чтобы потом легче дорабатывать код было. Из разряда вы внесли изменение в одном месте, а трех других что-то сломалось. MVVM хоть и не полностью, но позволяет сильно снизить верятность попадания в такую ситацию. Материал легко освоить за час.

Comment: А вот что вам нужно обязательно освоить - это XAML и привязки данных `Binding`. Без них ничего нормального не получится.

Comment: Вот [возмем пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567). Попробуйте переписать его без MVVM и привязок данных (споилер - кода станет раза в 3 больше). Я написал то приложение за полтора часа, там всего около 200 строк кода, включая разметку. И кстати оно - хороший пример той динамичности, о которой вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Никто не запрещает писать под WPF в стиле WinForms.Просто с MVVM в силу его поддержки "из коробки" удобнее

Comment: Не хотите MVVM - используйте любой другой шаблон: MVC или MVP. Я бы предложил MVU - стильно, модно, молодёжно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На первый вопрос ответили. Для построения динамических приложений (если я правильно понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду, то используется Binding). К примеру что-то добавилось в БД и оно тут же отобразилось в Вашей программе за счет привязки данных. Вот тут https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php объясняется как и зачем