# UI элементы WPF не появляются из основного конструктора, но появляются по событию кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, ui

Есть такой код:

```
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Grid gridServ = new Grid();
        ServersGrid.Children.Add(gridServ);



        TextBlock serverName = new TextBlock();

        serverName.Text = "name";
        serverName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        serverName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        serverName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
        serverName.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        serverName.FontSize = 13;


        TextBlock serverDiscription = new TextBlock();
        serverDiscription.Text = "discription";
        serverDiscription.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        serverDiscription.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        serverDiscription.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);



        Button button = new Button();

        button.Width = 80;
        button.Height = size;
        button.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
        button.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        button.FontSize = 15;
        button.Content = "Играть";




        Style buttonStyle = new Style();

        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.FontFamilyProperty, Value = new FontFamily("Verdana") });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.BackgroundProperty, Value = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFE82F2F")) });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.ForegroundProperty, Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter { Event = Button.ClickEvent, Handler = new RoutedEventHandler(mainWindow.Button_Click) });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, Value = HorizontalAlignment.Right });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.VerticalAlignmentProperty, Value = VerticalAlignment.Top });
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.BorderThicknessProperty, Value = new Thickness(0) });
        button.Style = buttonStyle;


        Grid canvasBackground = new Grid();
        canvasBackground.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFFFF"));
        canvasBackground.Height = size;
        canvasBackground.Width = 792;
        canvasBackground.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        canvasBackground.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        canvasBackground.Margin = new Thickness(0, margin, 0, 0);


        Grid canvasName = new Grid();
        canvasName.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFC453"));
        canvasName.Height = size;
        canvasName.Width = 120;
        canvasName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        canvasName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;


        Grid canvasDiscription = new Grid();
        canvasDiscription.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFFFF"));
        canvasDiscription.Height = size;
        canvasDiscription.Width = 535;
        canvasDiscription.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        canvasDiscription.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;



        canvasName.Children.Add(serverName);
        canvasDiscription.Children.Add(serverDiscription);
        canvasBackground.Children.Add(canvasName);
        canvasBackground.Children.Add(canvasDiscription);
        canvasBackground.Children.Add(button);
        gridServ.Children.Add(canvasBackground);
```

Он рисует вот такую плашку на лаунчере (Название, описание, кнопка играть)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно чтобы эти плашки появлялись при вызове метода в основном конструкторе, но они не появляются. Появляются только если нажать на тестовую кнопку button (см скрин)

Резюмирую.
Так работает

```
     private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        Test();

    }
```

А так не работает:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Test(); // отсюда не работает

        RunList();
    }
```

Говорит эксепшн стаковерфлоу

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вам WPF, если вы не используете его основные возможности? В нем очень плохо работать с контролами (особенно создавать их) через код!

Comment: У меня все на XAML, кроме этой плашки. Мне нужно отрисовать эту плашку 10 раз через цикл вставляя в нее данные которые я получаю по API. Я же не могу сделать цикл в XAML ))

Comment: Пишите разметку в XAML. А не работает наверное потому что вы какое-то mainwindow coздаете в конструкторе mainwindow, конструктор которого создает mainwindow, где в конструкторе создается mainwindow, и снова вгутри создается mainwindow... и так далее до бесконечности. Если бы вы научились пользоваться отладчиком, ставить точки останова и выполнять код пошагово,этот вопрос бы не возник.

Comment: `Я же не могу сделать цикл в XAML`  - кто вам такое сказал? `ItemsControl` в помощь. А сейчас вы делаете бред.

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня направили. Пойду узнаю что такое коллекции и itemscontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас бесконечная рекурсия.

уберите эту строчку

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
```

А вот эту строчку

```cs
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter { Event = Button.ClickEvent, Handler = new RoutedEventHandler(mainWindow.Button_Click) });
```

Измените вот так

```cs
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter { Event = Button.ClickEvent, Handler = new RoutedEventHandler(this.Button_Click) });
```

Потому что не нужно создавать новое окно, а вместо этого обращаться к текущему.

Но вообще лучше из вместо этой каши наверстать разметку в XAML используя `ItemsControl` с привязкой к коллекции. [Вот примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+itemscontrol), особенно обратите внимание на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), он содержит практически всё, что вам нужно.

Comment: Черт возьми! Огромное вам спасибо! Вы просто человек бог! Здоровья вам побольше, я потратил на это несколько недель. Но теперь я отлично понимаю, что мне нужно выучить и куда копать, еще раз огромнейшее спасибо!