# Создание 3 и более еды для змейки

Tags: c#, массивы

Пишу простенькую игру со змейкой. Появился такой вопрос, я создал еду и добавил ее на форму. Еда добавляется на форму через рандом. Но когда я захотел создать 3 еды, они получаются в одном месте.

```
private void CreatFood()
        {
            
            FoodPosition.X = random.Next(0, 10);
            FoodPosition.Y = random.Next(0, 10);

        }
```

Здесь попробовал создать через массив 3 еды, но так как FoodPosition.X FoodPosition.Y ссылаются на одно и тоже число, получается 3 еды в одном месте

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
raphics graphics = e.Graphics;
           Brush food = Brushes.Blue;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
graphics.FillRectangle(food, new Rectangle(FoodPosition.X * CellSize, FoodPosition.Y * CellSize, CellSize, CellSize));
            }
}

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreatFood();
        }
```

Comment: Так у вас же только в одном месте заполняются координаты. Унесите CreateFood под цикл

Comment: нужно не заполнять еду три раза одним и тем же, а три раза создавать новые координаты для еды

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как мне вынести CreateFood в цикл чтобы были разные координаты для еды.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567 там WPF, но игровую логику можно брать почти "как есть".