# Странное отображение окна в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

До этого в основном работал с WinForms, поэтому не понимаю многих вещей. У меня есть конкретная ширина окна в 750px, внутри DockPanel и уже внутри него есть две кнопки сбоку по 25px и грид в 700px посередине. В теории все логично: 25 + 25 + 700 = 750, и в дизайнере выглядит ровно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на выходе я получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что боковые кнопки имеют разный размер. При том, что WindowStyle стоит в None, но сверху есть плашка. Весь код:

```
<Window x:Class="Widget.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widget"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="75" Width="750" WindowStyle="None">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Width="25" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></Button>
        <Grid Width="700">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="3"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="4"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="5"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="6"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="7"></Button>
        </Grid>
        <Button Width="25" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WPF

- Не надо ориентироваться на дизайнер, разметка в дизайнере может отличаться от разметки на результате, это нормально
- Не надо задавать расстояния и размеры в пикселях, максимум что можно в пикселях - это маленькие отступы

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="75" Width="750" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="5"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="6"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="7"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="8"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="9"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Но лучше использовать `ItemsControl` и привязку данных, чтобы не плодить повторяющийся код. WPF очень сильно отличается от Winforms, он проще, но используется совершенно другой подход к разработке ([пример с объяснением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), здесь много и других примеров, в том числе моих).