# С# как обрезать график на форме при помощи ползунков с двух сторон?

Tags: c#, winforms, график

Как вывести на форму график с ползунками для возможности обрезки его точек? Не в WPF, а в WinForms.
Пример[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написать свой юзерконтрол с кастомным рендером?

Comment: А если рассматривать библиотеки?

Comment: Тогда лучше рассматривать WPF

Comment: Без WPF не обойтись?

Comment: А зачем? Если есть подходящий набор инструментов, зачем изобретать велосипеды? Учите WPF, XAML и привязки данных Binding, учите шаблон проектирования MVVM, и будете такие задачи как орехи щелкать, окончательно забыв про Winforms как про страшный сон, как минимум потому что WPF в разы проще использовать. Вот, [поиграйтесь с кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1222045/373567). Если полностью разберетесь как он работает, многое станет ясно.