# Добавление изображений на панель с условием WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 5 изображений 500х500, и есть чекпоинты в виде кнопок. При инициализации приложения из файла загружается информация о том в на каком чекпоинте какие данные. На данный момент я уже сортирую эти данные, чтобы они вывдились. Но теперь мне надо выводить картинки вместо текста, как это можно сделать?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> checks = new List<string>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Стенд питья", "Энергетические батончики", "Туалет", "Медпункт", "Информация" };
    List<string> imagePaths = new List<string>();
    List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int k;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string path = @"D:\Programs\C#\Zadanie2\Zadanie2\Checkpoints\data.txt";
        string[] imagePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Programs\C#\Zadanie2\Zadanie2\Icons\");
        string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach(var s in str)
        {
            checks.Add(s);
        }
        foreach(var dir in imagePath)
        {
            imagePaths.Add(dir);
        }
    }


    private void check1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        images = new List<BitmapImage>();
        sb.Clear();
        string[] s;
        k = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        s = checks[k].Split();
        for(int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                continue;
            else
                list.Add(s[j]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] == "Yes")
            {
                sb.AppendLine(names[i]);
                images[i].UriSource = new Uri(imagePaths[i]);
                Uri uri = new Uri(imagePaths[i], UriKind.Absolute);
                imgDynamic1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
            }
        }
        resText.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

Код для первого чекпоинта, остальные сделаны подобным образом

Comment: Это код в стиле Winforms, под WPF [как-то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567) писать надо, с привязками данных.

Comment: Берите `ItemsControl` с подходящей панелью, собирайте коллекцию и вяжите шаблон элемента контрола к элементу коллекции.