# Ошибки привязки контекста

Tags: c#, wpf

Ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml window:

```
<Window x:Class="prod_bw.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:prod_bw"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:prod_bw.Models"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <models:Game />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код Game:

```cs
namespace prod_bw.Models
{
    internal class Game
    {

        public int Kills { get; }
        public int Deaths { get; }

        public Game(int kills, int deaths)
        {
            Kills = kills;
            Deaths = deaths;
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал реализовывать контекст `INotifyPropertyChanged` в Game, не помогло. решение постоянно пересобирал.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш конструктор требует 2 аргумента `int kills` и `int deaths`. Вы их не можете никак передать создавая класс таким образом в XAML. Поясните, что вы хотите сделать то? И зачем вам такой конструктор? И почему именно свойства неизменяемые, содержат только геттеры `{ get; }`? Проблему решить легко, но только если знать, что за задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @aepot, хочу создать модель для использования в DataTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вникая в подробности, можно сделать так, убрав конструктор с параметрами, либо сделать конструктор без параметров `public Game() { ... }`.

```
public class Game
{
    public int Kills { get; set; }
    public int Deaths { get; set; }
}
```

То есть сделать класс публичным `public`, а свойства изменяемыми `{ get; set; }`

Тогда создать класс в XAML можно так

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <models:Game Kills="5" Deaths="10"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Если нужны нули, то `Kills="5" Deaths="10"` задавать необязательно, можно убрать.

Затем, если нужно будет чтобы UI контролы могли отслеживать изменения в модели, нужно будет реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Подробнее об этом я уже рассказывал и показывал в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567).