# Проблема с многопоточностью: закрывается программа

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пишу змейку на WPF. Всё просто: сетка grid и зелёная точка (голова змеи). Хочу чтобы змейка, а для начала хотя бы её без брюшная часть, двигалась в заданном направлении, а при нажатии клавиш передвижения менялось направление её движения. Движение змейки хочу сделать в отдельный поток: змейка двигается постоянно, а в другом потоке обрабатывалось событие нажатия клавиши для смены направления.

```
    int x = 6;
    int y = 6;

    enum Direction
    {
        Left = 1, Right = 2, 
        Up   = 3, Down  = 4, Stop = 0
    }
    Direction DirectionMove;

    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DirectionMove = Direction.Right;
        StartPosition(x, y);
        Thread moveSnake = new Thread(MoveSnake);
        moveSnake.Start();
    }
    public void MoveSnake()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int r = rnd.Next(1, 13);
        Grid.SetColumn(SnakeHead, r);
    }
```

Запускаю поток в MainWindow. Когда собираю проект не выдаёт никаких ошибок и пишет об успешной компиляции, но не появляется окна приложения.

Как угодно меняю код метода MoveSnake, но игра разве что может начать запускаться ненадолго и закрываться.

```
public void MoveSnake()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5)
        {
            i++;
            Grid.SetColumn(SnakeHead, i);
        }
    }
```

Ощущение, будто после выполнения действий в потоке программа прекращает жизнь

Comment: В диспетчере задач процесса программы тоже нету, значит программа всё-таки запускается, а потом закрывается

Comment: В UI приложениях обычно есть основной UI поток и остальные не-UI потоки. Так вот менять UI элементы можно только из UI потока, а вы просто запускаете какой то новый поток и что то делать с гридом пытаетесь. Так это не сработает. У вас WPF? Вот и пользуйтесь проверенными годами приемами для WPF - читайте про привязки, MVVM и прочее

Comment: хорошо, начну рыть в эту сторону. Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567 вы не можете работать с напрямую контролами из фонового потока

Comment: помимо указанной тут проблемы с изменением визуальной части (неправда, что это можно делать только из основного потока, главное из того, который создал контрол, так называемая [STA модель](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/documents_WPF/level31/31_1.php)), есть и другая проблема. исключения в дополнительных потоках по умолчанию не обрабатываются и о проблемах без регистрации своего обработчика не узнать.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов я специально построил свой комментарий так, чтобы он не противоречил нескольким UI потокам (приглядитесь к тексту и увидите это), но при этом не перегружал автора этой информацией, так как она для него бесполезна.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов STA модель - это маршаллирование выполняемого кода в управляемом потоке в основной физический UI поток, разницы ноль, оно даже и называется Single-Threaded Apartment, однопоточное оно. И дедлоки те же, все как при работе с одним потоком.

Comment: [UI поток может быть не один](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#multiple-windows-multiple-threads), как раз для избежания дедлоков